# Writing a custom mysql query to order wordpress users by a custom user meta field

Tags: mysql, wordpress

Basically, I need to order a list of WordPress users by the city they live in.  I've got a custom user meta field for city, and I've got the query working properly, but the query lists everyone who hasn't filled out a city at the beginning since it places blank fields at the beginning of the order.

What I need is to figure out how to only select and display users who have given a value other than blank in the city field.  Unfortunately, I've found myself stumped.

Any thoughts on how to do this?  Also, if anyone knows a way to orderby a custom user meta field using wp_user_query as opposed to this mess, I'm all ears.

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$limit = 10;
$offset = ($paged - 1) * $limit;
$key = 'city';

$sql = "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS {$wpdb->users}.* FROM {$wpdb->users}

INNER JOIN {$wpdb->usermeta} wp_usermeta ON ({$wpdb->users}.ID = wp_usermeta.user_id)
INNER JOIN {$wpdb->usermeta} wp_usermeta2 ON ({$wpdb->users}.ID = wp_usermeta2.user_id)
WHERE 1=1
    AND wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'wp_capabilities'
    AND CAST(wp_usermeta.meta_value AS CHAR) LIKE '%\"subscriber\"%'
    AND wp_usermeta2.meta_key = '$key'
ORDER BY wp_usermeta2.meta_value ASC
LIMIT $offset, $limit";

$site_users = $wpdb->get_results($sql);

$found_rows = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT FOUND_ROWS();");

foreach ($site_users as $site_user) { 
    // user info here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
...
WHERE 1=1
    AND wp_whatever.name_of_city IS NOT NULL
    AND LENGTH(wp_whatever.name_of_city) > 0
    AND wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'wp_capabilities'
...
```